# spring feign request giving error no suitable converter

Tags: spring-boot, wiremock

SO i have a feign client as follows:

```
@FeignClient(name = "ServiceClient", url = "${base.url}", configuration = FeignClientConfig.class)
public interface ServiceClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/v1/failed", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    List<Info> getData();

}
```

Error:

```
 "Error message: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.List<com.example.Info>] and content type [application/octet-stream]"
```

So im running this service with a docker wiremock server, testing in postman it gives me a json string value that is valid.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

was missing the following in mapping:

```
"headers": {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"  
},
```